# Map API v2 : No permission

Tags: android, google-maps

Here my `Manifests` snippet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Here my `fragment's` snippet:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        setInfoWindowAdapter();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            this.googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.no_permissions), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

When I start in one Android 4.3  the map work fine. But if I start on Android 6.0 I get message (Toast) ` **No permission**

Comment: have you added onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: I think you need `run time permission`

Comment: How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing your app on Android 6+ your code is working correct. You need to get runtime permission from user on Android 6+. Here is how you can do it:

```
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    } else {
          //permission is already granted
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //granted
                } else {
                    //not granted
                }
            } else {
                //not granted
            }
        }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***First :*** try to use this to request the permission :

```
 boolean permissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    if(permissionGranted) {
        // {Some Code}
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 200);
    }
```

***Second :*** implementation of OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback

```
...implements  ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
```

***Third :*** override `onRequestPermissionsResult` method

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 200: {
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // {Some Code}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```